# WCF SOAP Service giving MaxRecievedByte error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I have an application that is throwing a lot of errors lately when consuming a third party web service. Specifically, I get the following error:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

I have checked the bindings in my web.config and they are pretty large as it is. Certainly larger than 65536 (16bit unsigned short.)

```
<binding name="InteractiveOrderHandlerBinding" 
         closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" 
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
        sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" 
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="327680" 
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="327680"
        messageEncoding="Text" 
        textEncoding="utf-8" 
        transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                    maxStringContentLength="81920000" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

This has been working fine in the past with this configuration and we haven't made any code changes involving this code or this configuration. I a thinking it may be an error reflected back from the server, perhaps THEY are receiving too much data from my code instead of the other way around? But I dont want to turn to them until I have done my due diligence and made sure its not anything on my side.

The app in question is an ASP.NET application running on Windows 2012. IIS7.

Here is the System.ServiceModel from my config. In all disclosure, my config has a huge System.ServiceModel that is actually in multiple files. Here are the elemetns relevant to this service call.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
       <endpoint address="https://webxml.choicepoint.com/multistate"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                 bindingConfiguration="InteractiveOrderHandlerBinding"
                 contract="ChoicePointWS.InteractiveOrderHandler" 
                 name="InteractiveOrderHandlerPort" />

    </clent>

   <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="InteractiveOrderHandlerBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="327680" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="327680"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="81920000" maxArrayLength="16384"
                 maxBytesPerRead="40960000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="102400000"
        maxBufferSize="102400000" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="infinite">
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000"
        maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="16384000"
        maxStringContentLength="81920000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="102400000"
               sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="infinite">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384000" maxBytesPerRead="40960000"
                        maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="16384000"
                        maxStringContentLength="81920000" />
      </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>    
</bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

TIA.

Comment: "**for incoming messages**" - if this is the response from the 3rd party web service, it is an issue on their end.  You can set the quotas on your end all you want, but they have *zero* effect on the quotas set on the service.

Comment: @Tim, right, that is what I am trying to ascertain. If it is an error being returned from my client and therefore there is an issue with my configuration being wrong (or being disregarded by the application for some reason) or is this an exception being thrown by the server and reported back to the client making the call which in turn raises its own exception.

Comment: My hunch is that it's the 3rd party vendor.  Enabling WCF tracing (if you haven't already) might help further.  What version of .NET is the application running? Did you assign the defined binding ("InteractiveOrderHandlerBinding") to the client endpoint you're using?  Can you post the rest of the `<system.serviceModel>` section of your config?

Comment: @Tim, I added in the relevant parts (To my knowledge). As I mention in the edit, that section is actually pretty huge and split among 5 different files because there are so many service calls my app make to internal systems and external systems.

Answer (score 0):

Is **"MaxRecievedByte error"** correct? It seems the error is more like **"maximum message size.. (65536)... exceeded"**.

I suspect this is your configuration. Not the third-party. Consistent with the (detailed) error you posted, I've seen the later error occur as a result of the **maxReceivedMessageSize** value being too small for the returned message. This error can *seem* sporadic but, in my experience, it can *actually* just be due to sometimes receiving an unexpectedly large response. Consider testing with the maximum value **2147283954** (I think).

I recommend tracing your settings with great care and making sure you've update the correct endpoint's, **basicHttpBinding**, **maxReceivedMessageSize**.

- [Docs.Microsoft: Transport Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-quotas)
- [Docs.Microsoft: Large Data and Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming)